# ASP MVC Resource in javascript variable encodes string

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following string in resource file.

> You can't do this.

And I display it as a tooltip on some button from it's attribute.

```
$(".completedButton").attr("title", "@(Resources.CompleteBtn)");
```

It shows the quotation mark like this.

> &#8217 ; //without the space

I tried with `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode`with no luck.
Any ideas on how should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Html.Raw()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
$(".completedButton").attr("title", "@Html.Raw(Resources.CompleteBtn)");
```